# Parallel Processing in FastAPI

Tags: fastapi

Concurrency and parallel processing are two different things.

I know that FastAPI supports concurrency. It can handle multiple API requests concurrently using async and await.

What I want to know is, if FastAPI also supports Multiprocessing and Parallel processing of requests or not?
If yes then how can I implement parallel processing of requests?

I have searched a lot but everywhere I found about concurrency only. I am new to FastAPI.

Comment: Usually you'll ask your ASGI-server of choice to run multiple workers (i.e. uvicorn or gunicorn, etc.); that way you get concurrency and can use async functionality inside a process, and can still run multiple instances in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

When running your app with Uvicorn or Gunicorn, you can specify how many workers/processes you want. In Uvicorn, you just need to pass `--workers N` as an argument, and in Gunicorn it's pretty much the same, with `--workers=N`. That will start `N` processes all receiving requests at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to handle multiple requests at once, you can define your routes as *def* instead of *async def*. FastAPI will handle the requests in separate threads and multiple requests will be handled at a time.

Comment: Answer seems incorrect

Comment: @youri and why is that ?

Comment: I think I misread. I can't upvote unless the answer is edited for some reason. Maybe you could add the link found in the banner above, quoting the relevant part as a summary? This one: [FastAPI runs api-calls in serial instead of parallel fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516140/fastapi-runs-api-calls-in-serial-instead-of-parallel-fashion)